# Custom 401 Error Page for SVN Server

Tags: svn, subdomain, http-status-code-401, errordocument

I have SVN server running on one of my domains as svn.mydomain.com and would like to setup a 401 error document for when the user authentication fails.

As svn isn't an actual folder or real subdomain, i'm confused as to where I can put the ErrorDocument 401 line.

It doesn't have to be in the .htaccess file, if it will work I could put it in the apache config, but not sure if that will work?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it into my virtual host definition file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/svn.mydomain.com

```
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/lib/svn
    # other svn-config goes here

    ErrorDocument 401 "Incorrect username or password"
</Location>
```

CU, arnep

Comment: That works great :-)    Now I just need to figure out what the relative path to my 401.php file should be